# Signal generated for closing the window?

Tags: linux, unix, centos, signals

I'm using centOs 6.3(Final) version. My question is which signal is generated on pressing the close button for a window? Is the close button equivalent to alt-f4? Or is my whole understanding is wrong and centOs does not use the signal model for it's graphical windows?

If possible please specify the source of the answer since I need to document it.

Thanks

Comment: What is your goal here exactly? What are you trying to do as a result of this close-window action?

Comment: I'm simply closing the terminal. I'm not trying to achieve anything by closing the terminal. I'm curious about which signal is sent to it.

Comment: Which signal is sent to the terminal/shell from the environment when you click the X on the window frame? I believe `WM_DELETE_WINDOW` or `DestroyRequest` are what you are looking for depending on the exact question.

Comment: Let's consider it's either WM_DELETE_WINDOW or DestroyRequest. Considering it's none of the UNIX signals, can I safely say it's not using the UNIX's signal model?

Comment: Correct. At the X11 level this has nothing to do with `signal(2)` or `signal(7)`. Though the application in the terminal might receive a signal killing it and I suppose the terminal might as well under some (hung or something) circumstances.

Comment: Nice. Please add it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming we are talking about at the `X11` level here then the signal you are looking for is likely `WM_DELETE_WINDOW` or the `DestroyRequest`/`DestroyNotify` event.

This has nothing to do (again at the `X11` level) with `signal(2)` or `signal(7)`. Though it is entirely possible that in some circumstances (hung processes or similar) that those signals would be used to terminate the terminal process.

It is also likely that the shell/etc. running inside the terminal are going to receive various signals which terminate their operation.

Answer (score 1):

As said [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1106377/349837): You can use [`wmctrl`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/wmctrl):

```
wmctrl -c appName
```

More aggressive would be to grep the PID to send a POSIX signal like SIGTERM (15, Ctrl-c) (see notes below).

#### Notes

- Very similar to [How can I kill a specific X window](https://askubuntu.com/a/833314/349837)
- You can also try [with `xdottool`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/87839/209677)